# Is it possible to write single line return statement with if statement?

Tags: python

Is is possible to return from a method in single line in python

Looking for something like this

```
return None if x is None
```

Tried above, and it is invalid syntax

I could easily do:

```
if x is None:
    return None
```

But just curious if I can combine above if statement into a single line

Comment: What is the harm in `return x`?

Comment: @thefourtheye What if `x` wasn't None?

Comment: OP didn't mention anything about the else part.

Comment: Be aware that functions return None implicitly if they don't reach a return statement. If this is the last statement in a function, it is equivalent to `return None if x is None else None`, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It is possible to write a standard "if" statement on a single line:

```
if x is None: return None
```

However the [pep 8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends against doing this:

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged

Comment: I would humbly argue that "if EXPR: return" is a permissible exception. The reason is that when debugging, "if EXPR: func()" (as per pep 8 example), it's not clear if func() was called or not. However when "if EXPR: return" is called, then we know EXPR was true because return exits the function.

Answer (score 89):

Yes, it's called a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
return None if x is None else something_else
```

You need an `else something` in a conditional for it to work.

Comment: But it's not clear that OP wants to return `False` if x is not `None`.

Comment: What if the calling function expects a string? ;)

Comment: Remember before PEP 308 when we had to emulate the ternary with an array? `return [False,None][x is None]`? Me neither… *runs away*

Comment: I'm pretty sure the function isn't supposed to return at all in the else case.

Comment: Functions in Python always return an implicit None if they lack an explicit return.

Comment: Clarification: The function isn't supposed to return *from that line* in the else case; it's supposed to keep executing.

Comment: @hus787 I'd like to clarify that `False` was just something I added. Of course, the OP could easily replace it with whatever he needs to return. It was not meant to be anything. Infact, I'll change it

Comment: @Haidro it's not about returning `False` or `something_else` it's about the assumption that OP definitely wants the function to terminate and return at that point, which strictly speaking is not mentioned in the question. Maybe OP wants the function to proceed with something *else* if the condition is negative.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Is this expression and accepted expression are same? I don't think so. It looks same as `return test ? true_express : false_expression;` in C

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes, they are not same. An `else` is required in the accepted expression to make them identical.

Comment: NOTE to clarify: You can only use the `return` operator once in a ternary expression. The following will not work: return `"Yes" if value >= True else return "No"`

Comment: @BryanDimas `return "yes" if value else "No"`

Comment: No, I think the idea is to do a conditional return (return only if condition is met). Your solution will always return.

Answer (score 8):

You could also try the `list[bool]` expression:

```
return [value, None][x == None]
```

Now if the second bracket evaluates to true, None is returned otherwise, the value you want to return is returned

Comment: This is silly when ternary expressions are possible. It made sense to do this before they existed, but now there's absolutely no reason to.

Comment: +1 Helped me realize that you can ONLY use the `return` operator ONCE in a ternary expression. `return "Yes" if value == True else "No"` will return "No" in the else statement.

Answer (score 8):

Disclaimer: don't actually do this. If you really want a one-liner then like nakedfanatic says just break the rule of thumb from PEP-8. However, it illustrates why `return` isn't behaving as you thought it might, and what a thing would look like that does behave as you thought `return` might.

The reason you can't say `return None if x is None`, is that `return` introduces a statement, not an expression. So there's no way to parenthesise it `(return None) if x is None else (pass)`, or whatever.

That's OK, we can fix that. Let's write a function `ret` that behaves like `return` except that it's an expression rather than a full statement:

```
class ReturnValue(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.value = value

def enable_ret(func):
    def decorated_func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except ReturnValue as exc:
            return exc.value
    return decorated_func

def ret(value):
    raise ReturnValue(value)

@enable_ret
def testfunc(x):
    ret(None) if x is None else 0
    # in a real use-case there would be more code here
    # ...
    return 1

print testfunc(None)
print testfunc(1)
```

Comment: This is definitely not how you should do things, as you say, but I thought it was a little clever at least.

Comment: @kqr: I like to combine fashionable things (function decorators) with deeply unfashionable things (exceptions as non-error flow control) ;-) But the main point is to illustrate that `return` isn't an expression, so the only way to use an expression to get out of a function is to throw something. Or a `yield`-expression, but that's not generally applicable.

Comment: This is a inverse answer, like a "Not False" kinda answer. It explains why one should not do something. Thank you for posting this, quite a creative aproach to things. I enjoyed reading it over my cup of morning coffee.